# cannot load txt as numeric matrix

Tags: r

The following code is to load my matrix (in float/double) into R script. But the final matrices are not numeric. what is wrong with my code? can anyone help?

```
datdir = paste(getwd(), '/../dat/', sep="")
trainX = read.table(paste(datdir, 'trainX.txt', sep=""), header=FALSE)
trainL = read.table(paste(datdir, 'trainL.txt', sep=""), header=FALSE)
testX = read.table(paste(datdir, 'testX.txt', sep=""), header=FALSE)
testL = read.table(paste(datdir, 'testL.txt', sep=""), header=FALSE)
dims = dim(trainX)
trainX = as.numeric(trainX)
dim(trainX) = dims

dims = dim(trainL)
trainL = as.numeric(trainL)
dim(trainL) = dims

dims = dim(testX)
testX = as.numeric(testX)
dim(testX) = dims

dims = dim(testL)
trainX = as.numeric(testL)
dim(testL) = dims
```

Comment: could you dput your data so we can reproduce what your seeing? If its too big then dput(head(trainx))

Comment: As far as I know there is no `as.numeric.data.frame`. Thos are _not_ matrices. Aren't you getting an error that says: lists cannot be coerced to type 'double'? Perhaps try `obj = sapply(obj, as.numeric)` and skip the dimensioning which should not be needed.